# How to add popup in magento ! [Help]

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I would like to restrict customers to purchase who are below 18 years of age to my website.
I would like to add a popup on my index like this http://prntscr.com/3wgag2
It should have 2 Buttons of Yes and No.

Can Anyone help me with the same ! I'm currently using Toocas plugin but that doesn't support what I requite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use color box or fancy box to create a pop-up. You can download colorbox jS from [here](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/).

The pop up should be loaded first time the customer visits the website. I have wrote a tutorial on my blog regarding it. Please check the link [Function to be execute for first time load](http://universalcoder.wordpress.com/2014/03/11/how-to-execute-function-on-first-load-using-javascript/)

Create a simple template file with yes/no. If pressed Yes the pop-up will close else if pressed NO the user will be redirected to whichever page you would like. Maybe Terms and Condition etc or will not perform any action.

Call this template in the colorbox. You will learn how to do it from the colorbox tutorial given above.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm a newbee to magento, Can you just tell me where to upload that JS ?

Comment: you can add js in either js folder on root or in skin folder ie skin/frontend/yourtheme/default/js and you can include it in head file using xml